# How does PocketCasts do this transition/effect?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, material-design

PocketCasts material update has an awesome transition animation for their list items onClick. Is this done by adding a view/fragment to the existing Coordinator Layout for the activity? Any ideas on how I can implement this?

[image: LEFT: Shown upon clickin a list item. "Pops up" from bottom. RIGHT: Scrolling the "pop up" brings it to cover the whole screen]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's all custom code based around raw touch events with an OnTouchListener, a GestureDetector (onScroll, onFling, etc) and an OverScroller for helping to calculate the velocity things should travel at.

The view itself is just a class that extends FrameLayout which we move up and down in code.

Source: I wrote it ;)

Comment: So incredible that the creator himself answers my question! I had just listened to a Fragmented podcast with Phillip Simpson, and now here you are. I'm excited to read your code and now follow your blog. Thank you.

Comment: @rustyshelf what are the chances that you could open source that part of the code/view? :) or write a gist which does something very similar!

Answer (score 5):

Flipboard have open sourced their bottomsheet implementation.

https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet

It might be worth checking it out before you try to write your own version, @rustyshelf is a genius and it is near impossible. ;)